# How can I make this animation "Rail Text" seen on example

Tags: html, css

I am very curious about how this rail text animation is made ("Creativity meets healthy food")

https://www.studiogusto.com/project/misura/

I've looked thousands of css generator webs and I can't find that animation! When going into developer tools, I don't understand why they copy and paste it so many times. Does anybody has a clue? I'd like to use it to put an "under construction" in my own web.

I tried to look for animation examples and I don't find it. When inspecting the code, I don't understand why they copy and paste it so many times.

Please note I am a beginner :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

... it looks like a CSS TRANSFORMATION of the block of text. And there's always the option to use something like GreenSock js lib (that's a whole different bag of possibilities though)

[image]